# commit using previous commit message without duplicate commit

Tags: git, github

Sorry for the title, it sounds confusing but how to avoid extra commit same message, here's the scenario. I modified some files, I do `git add . && git commit -m 'done something'`..

Later on when I PR into develop branch I realised I accidendally left a `'console.log(x)'`, now how can I remove that thing without having to say `git commit -m 'removed unwanted console.log'`?

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly you just want to edit last commit? If it is the case, you should use git commit --amend option.

Comment: how to commit without add?

Comment: Ok I will be more precise. You should use `git add` to choose files which you want to edit in your previous commit and then use `git commit --amend`. For example you commited 2 files `Example1.js` and `Example2.js` and you want to change Example1. You edit the code in Example1 then you are using `git add Example1.js` and `git commit --amend`.

Comment: If you do not like to use console, you can always use some IDE with integrated git options, for example IntelliJ IDEA or some graphical interface like TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 1):

You can amend your last commit: After removing the unwanted line, add the changed file (`git add path_to_file`) and commit via 
`git commit --amend`. This will change your previous commit to also include the amended changes, i.e. to *not* include your log line.

This will, however, change the previous commit that was already pushed to the remote. You should only do this if you're completely sure no one else is working on top of your old commit.

Since you altered history, the subsequent push has to be forced (`git push --force`) to overwrite your old commit.

Comment: don't have to do git add ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course you have to. I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: then how many commit I will have? 2? it suppose to be just one.

Comment: It will be just one commit. `--amend` adds your staged changes to the changes of the previous commit and commits all that as *one*  new commit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Commit options > Ammend Last Commit
I hope it helps.